# Sort list of strings using icu-dotnet library for Myanmar collation

Tags: c#, .net-core, icu

I want to sort list of strings using icu-dotnet library for Myanmar collation.

It throw an exception while creating collator for myanmar.

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("my-MM");
using (var collator = Collator.Create(cultureInfo.Name))
{
    int compareResult = collator.Compare("သန်တ", "သန္တ");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This throws an *ArgumentException* because there are no predefined collation rules for *my-MM* in ICU. However, there are rules for *my*, so the following would work:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("my");
```

Or you could allow the fallback to *my* by passing *FallBackAllowed*:

```
using (var collator = Collator.Create(cultureInfo.Name, Collator.Fallback.FallbackAllowed))
{
}
```

You can see the predefined collators by looking at the [icu4c source tree](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/tree/master/icu4c/source/data/coll).

The full code to sort a list of strings:

```
var list = new List<string> {"foo", "baz", "bar", "zoo"};

using (var collator = Collator.Create("en-US"))
{
    list.Sort((s1, s2) => collator.Compare(s1, s2));
}
```

Comment: I want to know how to sort list of string using order by or other method to sort with collator.